# User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type in asp core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i create this class and it have this constructor :

```
 public class ReturnResult : ImplicitReturnResult
{
    public bool Success { get; }
    public ResultStatus Status { get; }
    public string Message { get; }

    public ReturnResult(bool Success, ResultStatus Status, string Message = null)
    {
        this.Success = Success;
        this.Status = Status;
        this.Message = Message ?? Status.ToDisplay();
    }


}
```

and in this class i need to use constructor this class :

```
 public class ImplicitReturnResult
{
    public static implicit operator ReturnResult(OkResult result)
    {
        return new ReturnResult(true, ResultStatus.Success);
    }
}
```

i using this code but it show me this error :

> Error  CS0556  User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing

whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for the C# compiler to not have to search through *all* types from *all* referenced assemblies to find whether any particular user-defined operator exists for a conversion, the rules are that either the input *parameter* or the *return type* of any user-defined conversion must match the type in which the operator is defined.

```
public class ImplicitReturnResult
{
    public static implicit operator ReturnResult(OkResult result)
    {
        return new ReturnResult(true, ResultStatus.Success);
    }
}
```

Neither the return type (`ReturnResult`) nor the parameter (`OkResult`) to this operator is `ImplicitReturnResult`. That's why it's not allowed. You need to move this operator into `ReturnResult` itself, not its base class.

It's not enough that one type *inherits* from the other. It has to be an exact type match.